# Homestead ip different from configuration file

Tags: laravel-5, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, homestead

I'm trying to install Laravel+Vagrant+Homestead on my Ubuntu 14.04. My /etc/hosts have this line:

```
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

and my .homestead/Homestead.yaml have

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
...
folders:
    - map: ~/blog
      to: /home/vagrant/blog
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/blog/public
```

That's because I have made a test with "laravel new blog" before, so I'm trying to use this as a test.

But when I put "homestead.app" in my browser, it says:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://homestead.app/

    Connection to 127.0.53.53 failed.

The system returned: (111) Connection refused
```

Where is this address "127.0.53.53" coming from?

Also, when I issued the command

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

and received

```
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.7) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.7/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.7) for 'virtualbox'!
```

there shouldn't exist a "laravel/homestead" visible when I open virtualbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't own homestead.app so don't use it as a URL.

That IP is telling is [ICANN informing you of a name collision](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2-2014-08-01-en%20ICANN%20informing%20you%20there's%20a%20name%20collision).